# Can I use die to fill a variable?

Tags: php

When I fill variables, can I do something like this?:

```
$type = isset( $_GET['type'] ) ?  $_GET['type'] : die();
```

By doing so, if 'type' is not in the request, my function will exit. Is this the correct way to use die()?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want your *function* to exit, use `return`. However, it's not an expression, so you'll need to change it to an `if` statement:

```
if(!isset($_GET['type'])) {
    return;
}

$type = $_GET['type'];
```

If you do want your whole page to stop execution, then yes, that's correct (but I'd still use an `if` for clarity).

Comment: @David No way, not evil! Just not appropriate for this purpose. Ternary is for conditional value assignment or return, not complex branching or script termination.

Comment: @Brad / Michael I suppose I mean misuse of it...when it's used properly it's clear what it's doing but far too often it is misused.

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no. Yes in that what you're doing is technically correct and will terminate the script if the variable is not present, but no in that you if you ever want to test your code you shouldn't use the `die` construct. PHP is an object oriented language (since version 5) and a very powerful one at that. It supports the use of exceptions for advanced error-handling which you might want to use here.

Answer (score 1):

you can't use `die()` to fill a variable. `die()` terminates your code. Instead, you may consider the code below:

`$type = isset( $_GET['type'] ) ?  $_GET['type'] : null;`

Comment: @minitech, Can you elaborate on what you are trying to explain with your codepad example?

Comment: @Brad: You can put it in an inline conditional, no problem. Unless that's not what sikas meant?

Comment: @minitech, Oh, this is sikas' post...  I was just curious what you were getting at, that's all.  I don't think sikas is saying that you can't `die()` there.  I think he's saying that since execution stops, it's useless.

Comment: @Brad You got my point here .. better to provide a custom 404 than to just show a white empty page `die();` or some plain text `die('Some Plain Text');`

Answer (score 1):

The [Ternary Operator Docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) says that this:

```
$type = isset( $_GET['type'] ) ?  $_GET['type'] : die();
```

Is identical to this if/else statement:

```
if ( isset( $_GET['type'] ) )
    $type = $_GET['type'];
else 
    $type = die();
```

It works because `die()` will be called and will stop the script execution, but isn't a good practice. Insted of this a think is better you use and if/else statement and simply call `die()` if $_GET['type'] doesn't exist, as below.

```
if ( isset( $_GET['type'] ) )
    $type = $_GET['type'];
else 
    die('type not found');
```

Answer (score 0):

The **die()** function will end your entire PHP process, not just exit the function you're in. Beyond that, the code is relying on the fact that PHP is kind of goofy. **die()** is strictly supposed to be a void function, but your call is depending on it returning *something* -- which it does, but shouldn't.

What you really want is a straightforward **if** statement:

```
if( ! isset($_GET['type']) )
    return;

$type = $_GET['type'];
```

The other thing is, if this code is in a function, the value of $type will not be preserved unless it's been declared as global.